# Fetch_Assoc() on Non-Object

Tags: php, mysqli

So, I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object
```

And it says the error is on line 220.

Which line 220 is:

```
while ($field = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
```

$result:

```
$tbl_name = "savage";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name LIMIT $start, $limit ORDER BY `id` DESC";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

I'm not sure if it is because $tbl_name is in a variable or what, but I haven't got an idea of how to fix this. Might be a simple answer, but hopefully you can help! Let me know if I need to provide more!

Forgot to include:

```
  $limit = 10;
  if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;
  } else {
    $page = 0;
    $start = 0;
  }
```

In this case $_GET['page'] is not set.

Comment: `if (!$result) echo $mysqli->error;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIMIT` goes after `ORDER BY`

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
```

- **http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html**

Example from the manual:

```
SELECT
    [ALL | DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW ]
      [HIGH_PRIORITY]
      [STRAIGHT_JOIN]
      [SQL_SMALL_RESULT] [SQL_BIG_RESULT] [SQL_BUFFER_RESULT]
      [SQL_CACHE | SQL_NO_CACHE] [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS]
    select_expr [, select_expr ...]
    [FROM table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ... [WITH ROLLUP]]
    [HAVING where_condition]
    [ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ...]
    [LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
```

Comment: Fastest gun in the west!

Comment: @Darren *With a six-gun in my hand...* ;-)

Comment: Thankyou! Worked perfectly, I should have noticed that! :) Will accept answer once time is up!

Comment: @LunarSAF You're welcome, glad to have been of help, *cheers*